# How to resolve com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

I am using iBatis for ORM of application. My sqlmapconfig.xml file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">
<sqlMapConfig>
<sqlMap resource="file:com${file.separator}platysgroup${file.separator}lmexserver${file.separator}mobile${file.separator}dao${file.separator}ibatis{file.separator}lmexusermobileinfo.xml" />
</sqlMapConfig>
```

I need to use file separator as we are developing using two operating system Ubuntu and Windows XP. but when I run my application it show me a exception as below:

```
com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.
Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource file:comfile.separatorplatysgroupfile.separatorlmexserverfile.separatormobilefile.separatordaofile.separatoribatis{file.separator}lmexusermobileinfo.xml
```

The file lmexusermobileinfo.xml exist in package com.platysgroup.lmex.server.core.dao.ibatis

Please help me to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried  both environments with each type of slash? There are only 4 combinations to test and maybe you're dealing with a problem that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `${file.separator}` in `sqlmapconfig.xml` with '/' or '.'